# Why does printing a tabulator not always print a tabulator but a space?

Tags: python, tabulator

this might be a simple question but I haven't found a solution or a similar question yet.
When printing

```
print(str(n) + "\t" + str(abs(moved_nm.value)) + "\t" + str(truncate(diff_2, 2)) + "\t" + str(truncate(diff_abs, 2)))
```

It prints

```
3   9999375 9935347.98  64027.01
```

Why does the first \t print a tabulator while the rest don't?

Comment: Because tabulator is not n spaces but mark at every n spaces... So it moves to nearest mark

Comment: From your output, it appears that your 'tab size' is 4 characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually does print tabulators. The ASCII code of your string is:

```
51 9 57 57 57 57 51 55 53 9 57 57 51 53 51 52 55 46 57 56 9 54 52 48 50 55 46 48 49
```

(you can check [here](https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-to-ascii))

The code for tabulator is `9` and your string contains 3 of them, 1 between each word.

Note that a tabulator does not always appear to have the same length, it adjusts the length to get to the beginning of the next column. It is useful in case you want a column that starts at the same position at each line, but be careful to not allow to long words or it will expand until the next column beginning.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a possibility to make them the same length? It just bothers me a little, I need them to be sperated by a tabulator for further calculations so using spaces is a no.

Comment: If you want same length spaces I would recommend several whitespaces, for example `" "*3`